# In Swagger UI, how to customize body input ui (model schema UI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using 'swagger UI' with Swagger 2.0 in C#.Net app, and displaying Get, Post, Delete endpoints.

For Post, I'm passing 'model schema' as a body(input parameter).

Its difficult to use one textarea for to input class object.

Is it possible to customize body parameter UI alone... like separate input boxes for all the parameters in class object(model schema)?

SO that, for post method, with model schema parameter, UI will be separate textboxs for all the parameters in the class object(model schema)..

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that clicking on the `Example value` on the **Data Type** column actually fills in the body value with the default entity content? That's a start to avoid typing it all.

Nonetheless, you [can also override](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/tree/swagger_2.0#customizing-the-swagger-ui) the current Swagger UI display, changing [existing views content](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/search?p=1&q=body-textarea&utf8=%E2%9C%93) to match the `text-area` to be transformed to a custom-made parser displaying property textboxes instead of a single textarea.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Clicking on the "Example value" on the "Data Type" column filling in the body value with default values, properly.

Comment: In my use-case, I have very big class/body parameter to post. As a end-user, it's not easy to fill all the values within a textarea(one textarea). I'm looking for a separate Textbox for each parameter in the body value.

Comment: You are right..., as you mentioned, I'm looking for separate textboxes instead of a single textarea. How to convert/override generically(to support all the similar body paramaters)?

Comment: Swagger UI is providing a generic control for this as a text area. I didn't find anywhere something similar to your request, so you can actually contribute to it by building it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddControllers()
        //Used to Add Input field to the Swagger UI
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressInferBindingSourcesForParameters = true;
            });
```